# Can't assemble the pot, it keeps breaking

Tags: samorost-3

I can put the pot together entirely, but it still falls apart. What do I need to do to get it to stay together?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go left, you will meet a group of animals. Once you have succeeded with that quest (all the way to the ghost mushroom), you will get a ball of glue.

Comment: This is a nice, non-spoiler-y answer. I too was frustrated by putting this item together, as the game gave several hints that I was on the right track... and it took some time to figure out an additional item was needed to finish.